# SSIS package slower in SQL Agent job than running it manually

Tags: sql, ssis

We have developed ssis package that downloads files in xml format from ftp and than processes and inserts in respective tables. We have a requirement to insert only unique and recent most records, so we used `lookup` to perform the comparison. We are encountering a problem that it is too much slow while scheduled via SQL Agent job, and works okay if we run it manually.

Comment: Check if this applies to any of your SQL queries/procs called by the package:   http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: When you run it manually, is it using all the same data sources, destinations, lookups etc and is the data volume of the source file the exact same as the Agent execution?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the SQL Server Agent job step as a different account. I ran into a similar issue and when I switched from using a proxy for a service account to a proxy for my own admin account, the job began running in the same amount of time as starting it manually. So I assume it has to do with the difference in permission levels but wasn't able to dig into it further.

Comment: I am facing same issue. In this case, my agent account is added as an Admin to local machine as well as SQL Server but it is very slow as a Job whereas running it from command prompt invoking dtexec is fast(twice to thrice)